# ExpandableListView with ViewPager as child-elements executes getChildView twice

Tags: android, android-viewpager, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to create an expandable list with viewpagers as subviews. The problem is now that with my code it calls the `getChildView` method ***twice*** and thus creates my viewpager twice.

I also tried it with the `TextView` (which is the sample code I posted here for convenience) to simplify the code but the same issue arose.

My best guess is it has something to do with the height property of the layouts but no matter how i changed it, I couldn't resolve the issue. 
Please help. I am totally lost. I used a tutorial for this code and I seem to be the only who has that issue judging from the youtube comment section. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZxZIFnJ9jE)

(If you need any other part of the code please let me know.)

**delete.xml** file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sukahead">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suka"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="suka"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**sublist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/sublist">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dict_entry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="test"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:onClick="lookup_word"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/search_result_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#333"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"/>


     </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
package com.lunaticcoding.linguodict;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpendableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> data;
    private HashMap<String, String[]> listHashMap;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String pageData[];

    public ExpendableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> list, HashMap<String, String[]> hashMap) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = list;
        this.listHashMap = hashMap;
    }


    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return listHashMap.get(data.get(groupPosition)).length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return data.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return listHashMap.get(data.get(groupPosition))[childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sublist, null);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dict_entry);
        textView.setText(data.get(groupPosition));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.delete, null);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suka);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity** (only OnCreate)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        searchResults = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_list);

        list_results = new ArrayList<>();
        examples_results = new HashMap<>();
        list_results.add("test1");
        list_results.add("test2");
        list_results.add("test3");

        String pageData1[] = new String[]{"si", "siiii"};
        String pageData2[] = new String[]{"jifasfa", "sfasdfasiii"};
        String pageData3[] = new String[]{"jifasfa", "sfasdfasiii"};
        examples_results.put(list_results.get(0), pageData1);
        examples_results.put(list_results.get(1), pageData2);
        examples_results.put(list_results.get(2), pageData3);

        searchResultsAdapter = new ExpendableListAdapter(this, list_results, examples_results);
        searchResults.setAdapter(searchResultsAdapter);

        lastExpandedPosition = -1;
        searchResults.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if(lastExpandedPosition != -1 && (lastExpandedPosition != groupPosition)){
                    searchResults.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
                }
                lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sub_list.xml the layout_height is "wrap_content". Change it to a fixed height (some dp) or match_parent and it will work.

Reason: 
wrap_content has to calculate the height of the layout content it has to match thus reloading the layout afterwards -> creating the list more than once.