# OnitemClick returns the wrong string value

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview

Working with Firebase. I'm trying to populate an image view, Textview using Firebase and a custom listview. when the user selects an item from the list it is supposed to save the id of the Firebase item to the user section of my database.

All items populate correctly in the list view but when i select an item only position 0 and 5 are actually working the rest of the items always return  pos 1-5 looping back. can you please take a look at my code n tell me what I've done wrong thanks :)

```
private void Display_Images() {

    ListView listOfImages = findViewById(R.id.avatar_list);
    listOfImages.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            FirebaseAuth mAuth  =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String userid = mAuth.getUid();
            avatar_id = AVATAR_ID.get(position);
            DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid);
            db.child("avatarID").setValue(avatar_id);
            finish();
        }
    });

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Image_Selector>(this, Image_Selector.class,
            R.layout.avatars, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Avatars")) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Image_Selector model, int position) {
            imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.image);
             tv = v.findViewById(R.id.tvavatar);
             AVATAR_ID.add(model.getID());
            tv.setText(model.getName());
            Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getUrl()).into(imageView);

        }


    };
    listOfImages.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is my database

```
 "Avatars" : {
"Batman1" : {
  "id" : "Batman1",
  "name" : "Batman Logo",
  "url" : "url to image"
},
"Default" : {
  "id" : "Default",
  "name" : "Default",
  "url" : "url to image"
},
"Test" : {
  "id" : "Test",
  "name" : "TEST",
  "url" : ""
}
```

I'm trying to save the id as a string when an item in listview is clicked. Then Saving it to the user section of my database. example below.

```
"Users" : {
"F3vHZSClnPhE9cDjPeY5x0PuTmz1" : {
  "Username" : "Username Appears here.",
  "avatarID" : "here is where the id should be saved",
},
```

****EDIT****

this is my firebase model class

```
 public class Image_Selector {
String name;
String url;
String id;
public Image_Selector(String name,String url,String id){
   this.name = name;
   this.url = url;
   this.id = id;

}
public Image_Selector(){

}
 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

**** EDIT ****

Example of what is happening is if i select batman the id returned is batman1. but if i select Test item it still returns the id Batman 1. if i select Default it returns id default. I've tried adding a few more items to the database and Depending on the height and width of my custom listviewitem.xml will make a sort of loop. Only allowing me to capture ids that are from a list view item i can see. any items off screen will return the wrong id looping back to pos 0,1,2,3 and so on.

****EDIT****

Added Logs to my onitem click method

```
 String pos =  String.valueOf(position);
            Log.i("String_ID ",avatar_id);
            Log.i("String_POSITION ",pos);
            Log.i("String_USERID",userid);
```

The results came back as follows for each of the three items

item 1 in my listview is batman and returns

```
2019-07-11 12:04:51.152 3685-3685/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic 
I/String_ID: Batman1
2019-07-11 12:04:51.152 3685-3685/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic 
I/String_POSITION: 0
2019-07-11 12:04:51.152 3685-3685/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic 
I/String_USERID: F3vHZSClnPhE9cDjPeY5x0PuTmz1
```

item 2 in my listview is default and returns

```
2019-07-11 12:06:22.920 3685-3685/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic 
I/String_ID: Default
2019-07-11 12:06:22.935 3685-3685/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic 
I/String_POSITION: 1
2019-07-11 12:06:22.935 3685-3685/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic 
I/String_USERID: F3vHZSClnPhE9cDjPeY5x0PuTmz1
```

item 3 in my listview is test and returns

```
2019-07-11 12:07:18.983 3685-3685/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic 
I/String_ID: Batman1
2019-07-11 12:07:18.984 3685-3685/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic 
I/String_POSITION: 2
2019-07-11 12:07:18.984 3685-3685/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic 
I/String_USERID: F3vHZSClnPhE9cDjPeY5x0PuTmz1
```

so from this i have figured its something to do with the avatarid string
Ive added a log to the populate method to see if the actual model gives the right id in the first place

```
 String modelid = model.getID();
            Log.i("String_id_AtSource",modelid);

2019-07-11 12:20:34.504 3685-3685/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic 
I/String_id_AtSource: Test
```

and it gives the right id.
 so it has to be something to do with The Array AVATAR_ID?

*****EDIT 21/7/2019******

Ok so using the answer below it seemed to be fixed. but since ive added more items to the database. it seems still to be doing it. So from further testing, i can tell you when it happens..

all ids capture correctly until you scroll. this means that as long as all the list items fit on the screen they return the right id. hence why i thought it was fixed with the below answer.

i first had the imageview size set to 300dp squared so it was a big list view item hence only 2 items click working correctly. changing the size to 90dp squared made it so the 5 items fit.

the list items ids return in a loop from the first 5. e.g clicking item 6 returns id of item 0, item 7 returns id of item 1 n so on. Yet the position of the list view item and all data inside the list is correct

The first page all work correctly.  I've removed the image view to try to see if it was perhaps the image was too big

The second page all ids return in a loop from the first page e.g.  the item Mario returns the Id for Batman and the item spiderman returns id for DJ Lama

Comment: added AVATAR_ID.add(model.getID()); to my code must have deleted when testing lol

Comment: is `avatar_id` is a global variable or local?

Comment: It's a Global variable

Comment: Inside your `setOnItemClickListener`, please log the value of `position`, `userid `, `avatar_id`. Then try to click at 1st, 2st, 3st item and post the log to your question then we can help you

Comment: @PhanVanLinh added the logs pal. from this its shown me that its the avatarid string that causes the problem. at position 2 and onward it jumps back to 0 postion which is batman1

Comment: This is just a guess in the dark: If you add more than 2 items, are they visible? Or are just item 1 and 2 visible?
Could it be the case that the AdapterView implementation recycles the item views? That would mean there are only ever as many physical views as there are items visible, and the adapter would just update the views.
You could try logging the size of `listOfImages`.

Comment: No Daniel the other items are visible this only happens when items are clicked

Comment: OP says its fixed and there is no explanation. What was the issue and what is the fix?

Comment: Not fixed jin mate

Comment: Please follow the code style man.
https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/code-style

Comment: problem still happening see my post edit

Comment: the getters & setters of the model are dramatically messy and do not match the field names ...which does not really aid the overall readability. here be dragons (won't touch that).

Comment: ive since re wrote the setter fields ill post them now

Comment: @markharrop with a major code cleanup, you might even find the issue by yourself... because the idea behind writing beautiful code is not necessarily the aesthetics, but the idea to sooner or later having to read & understand it again. down-scaling screenshots to 25% or 50% should also suffice to see how it looks alike, without having to scroll too much.

Comment: ive rewitten the code quite a few times now with same result

Comment: i have edited the setter section

Comment: how do i scale images down? can i do that in here or would i need export n do it manually?

Comment: @markharrop have you ever tried displaying the ID as text on the items? down-scaling images only works offline; eg. with GIMP (while this aids the general readability & convenience online). I'd suggest to drastically cut down on complexity... it cannot be that difficult, if only it wouldn't be such a mess. for example, simply tagging the items with the ID would be by far the least effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cause

The order in which `populateView()` is called for positions can't be predicted unless all the list fits in the screen. They won't be called all at once in the order of position otherwise. Therefore the list `AVATAR_ID` is invalid if the list is larger.

#### Solution

Replace `avatar_id = AVATAR_ID.get(position);`

with `avatar_id = ((Image_Selector)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getID();`

Comment: This has completely fixed the issue Anees. Thank you ❤️

Answer (score 6):

try fixing Imageview  height and width.

```
imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.height:150;
imageView.width:150;
```

Comment: It's already a fixed size Jin 300dp by 300dp why would this matter for getting a string Id from Firebase though

Comment: sometime you images are too big and you might be clicking on  previous image.Any way I don't think there was any code issue.Or you have default image and image is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

As a Temp I've added an extra text view to the customlistviewitem.xml for the id to go in to. I then populate the view and in the onclick, I capture the avatarid from the text view instead of the AVATARID Array and it works. I can always make the textview invisible

inside my populateView I added

```
tv1 = v.findViewByID(R.id.tv_avatar_id);
tv1.setText(model.getID);
```

then inside OnItemClick

```
tv1 = view.findViewByID(R.id.tv_avatar_id);
avatarid = tv1.getText().toString();
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do it than this.

Comment: 1. Instead of saving string to dummy TextView, try: `v.setTag(model.getID);` [in populateView] and `avatarid = (String)view.getTag();` [ in OnItemClick];

Comment: 2. Your AVATARID ArrayList in not populated correctly, this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600377/expandablelistview-with-viewpager-as-child-elements-executes-getchildview-twice Since you have only a few items now, so I suggest you log/toast the whole ArrayList and its size in OnItemClicked for debug;

Comment: 3. Your approach to implement **listview load more** or **endless list** is incorrect as user can scroll backwards which will add incorrect items. Try search with **listview load more** or **endless list** for samples/tutorials. Hope that helps!